# Why do I need to put dot forward slash when running a 'sh' command in Linux?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

I have found that if I have a .sh file in a certain directory then I can run it (using sh) from that folder with or without dot forward slash. So why even bother adding it?

Comment: If you can do that from any directory, then `.` is in your path, which means you're up for bad surprises in the future.

Comment: Read more about [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29)

Comment: you can have scripts stored in path and run it from anywhere in your FS, a script can have the same name if they are in multiple folders. To avoid confusion while running scripts, the best practice is to run it with the ./prefix to ensure that you are running the script present in the current folder only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please check http://www.linfo.org/dot_slash.html as well.
Basically this is a safety mechanism to indicate the program to execute is in the current directory and NOT a built-in command, a command in some other folder specified in the PATH etc.

From the link:

> Files in the current directory can be accessed for reading and writing by merely entering the command name (e.g., cat or vi) followed by the name of the file. That is, no absolute path is necessary. However, when execution is desired, either an absolute path (or its dot slash equivalent) or the inclusion of the directory containing the command's executable file in the PATH variable is necessary. This is a built-in safety mechanism.

If your script is running without ./ then it means the specific location is in the path or . is in the path as mentioned in comments.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your PATH is a list of directories which is searched to find files to execute.  If your command is in one of those directories it will be executed.  If it is in a different directory, then you need to indicate to the shell what directory it is in.  `.` means the current directory, so

```
./prog
```

will run the prog file found in the current directory

```
/some/other/path/prog
```

will run the file in the directort /some/other/path

and

```
subdir/prog
```

will run prog in subdir relative to your current directory.

To see what your path is set to type `echo $PATH`.