# Command Line Issue for uci-analyser chess program

Tags: shell, ubuntu, analysis, chess, uci

I'm currently trying to use uci-analyser found at this link:

https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/djb/uci-analyser/

I'm trying to run it on Ubuntu 21.0 impish. Used the source file. Confirmed C++ compiler and confirmed installation by going with the Readme.txt file by using the Makefile. Confirmed stockfish installed in Ubuntu via apt. Confirmed file "analyser" exists and permission for owner and group is "Read and write", Others "Read-only" and checked to allow to execute file as program.

Command tried

`analyse --engine stockfish --searchdepth 12 --annotatePGN games-uci.pgn > games-annotated.pgn`

Error

> analyse: command not found

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I need to put dot forward slash when running a 'sh' command in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34269027/why-do-i-need-to-put-dot-forward-slash-when-running-a-sh-command-in-linux)

Comment: You need exemute permissions in order to be allowed to execute something; it's not entirely clear from your exposition whether you have them. Anyway, basic questions about how to use your computer are probably better suitable for [ubuntu.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try
`./analyse --engine stockfish ...`